# React-Navigation (android) navigate error

Tags: react-native, navigation

My English level is very low because i'm from Korean.
then, i need you help guys..
i'm studying React-native (android)
i want switch my screen... but react navigation does not working.
i find this solution for 1 days... but i cant find solution...
please help me guys..

**HomePage.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity,StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {    
render() {             
  return (          
      <View style={styles.MasterContainer}>
          <NavBar/>
          <UserBar/>
          <View style={{height: 40,}}></View>
          <ButtonTab/>
          <Admob/>
          <TapBar/>
      </View>
  );
}
}

class NavBar extends React.Component {
render(){  
    const {navigation} = this.props;
    return(
        <View style={styles.NavBar}>
            <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold',fontSize: 18, color: 'white'}} onPress ={() => 
navigation.navigate('NavPg')}>더보기</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
 }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import HomePage from './screens/HomeScreen';
import NavPage from './screens'
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';

const App = createStackNavigator(
{
    Home: {screen:HomePage},
    NavPg: {screen:NavPage},
},
{initialRouteName:"Home", headerMode:'none'}
);

export default createAppContainer(App);
```

Comment: You're not passing the `navigation` as a prop to your `NavBar` component. This prop is only on HomePage component. You need to pass it like `<NavBar navigation={this.props.navigation} />`

Comment: i write <NavBar navigation={this.props.navigation}/>, onPress ={() => navigation.navigate('NavPg') 
but error come back.... cant find variable: navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use HOC of withNavigaion from react-navigation use below code hope it will work

```
 import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class NavBar extends React.Component {
render(){  
    const {navigation} = this.props;
    return(
        <View style={styles.NavBar}>
            <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold',fontSize: 18, color: 'white'}} onPress ={() => 
navigation.navigate('NavPg')}>더보기</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
 }
}
export default withNavigation(NavBar);
```

Comment: Can you check my new Question?

Answer (score 0):

I see your answer and try but your code is good and work! however my code is not working... tried in many ways but i haven't solved it.

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity,StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';


 class HomeScreen extends React.Component {    
 render() {                  
    const {navigation} = this.props;
  return (          
      <View style={styles.MasterContainer}>
          <NavBar navigation/>
          <UserBar/>
          <View style={{height: 40,}}></View>
          <ButtonTab/>
          <Admob/>
          <TapBar/>
      </View>
  );
 }
 }

 class NavBar extends React.Component {
 render(){                
    return(
        <View style={styles.NavBar}>
            <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold',fontSize: 18, color: 'white'}}     
 onPress={() => navigation.navigate('NavPg')}>더보기</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
 }
}
```

Error -> Can't find variable: navigation

Comment: you have to wrap export default withNavigation(COMPONENT_NAME)

Comment: where component name is you want to access navigation inside

Comment: sorry this is part of my scripts...
export default withNavigation(HomeScreen);

Answer (score 0):

Oops!! Solved it! Thanks you!!

**index.js**

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {    
render() {                          
  return (          
      <View style={styles.MasterContainer}>
          <NavBar navigation = {this.props.navigation}/>
          <UserBar/>
          <View style={{height: 40,}}></View>
          <ButtonTab/>
          <Admob/>
          <TapBar/>
      </View>
  );
}
}

class NavBar extends React.Component {
render(){            
    return(
        <View style={styles.NavBar}>
            <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold',fontSize: 18, color: 'white'}} 
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('NavPg')}>더보기</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
}
```